# How to use `GlobalObjectKey`s for scrolling to the certain widget? Now they are throwing "Duplicate GlobalKeys"exception

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen with list of widgets which is scrolling to selected the element on tap. To achieve this I use Scrollable.ensureVisible and GlobalObjectKeys. It usually works well except one case. If I am at my scroll screen and pushing this screen again by Navigator.pushReplacement occurs "Duplicate GlobalKeys detected in widget tree" error (if I push some other screen and then my scroll screen - everything is OK). But everything works well - app isn't crashing, scroll works as expected. Can't find a way to resolve this problem.

Minimal reproducible example (just tap FAB to reproduce the problem):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ScrollController _chipsScrollController = ScrollController();
  String _currentChip = 'Chip 1';
  static const _chips = [
    'Chip 1',
    'Chip 2',
    'Chip 3',
    'Chip 4',
    'Chip 5',
    'Chip 6',
    'Chip 7',
    'Chip 8',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 70,
          child: ListView.separated(
            controller: _chipsScrollController,
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 12, 16, 12),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: _chips.length,
            itemBuilder: (final BuildContext context, final int index) {
              return ChoiceChip(
                  key: GlobalObjectKey(_chips[index]),
                  label: Text(_chips[index]),
                  selected: _chips[index] == _currentChip,
                  onSelected: (final bool value) {
                    _currentChip = _chips[index];
                    Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                      GlobalObjectKey(_chips[index]).currentContext!,
                      alignment: 0.5,
                    );
                  });
            },
            separatorBuilder: (final BuildContext context, final int index) =>
                const SizedBox(width: 12),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => const MyHomePage(
              title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ig because you are using the same objectKye `GlobalObjectKey(_chips[index])`. I am just curious why do you need `pushReplacement` within the same route

Comment: Well, I have a very old app with loads of legacy code with drawer navigation, where there is such behavior. In fact it just refreshes a page that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need this (see comment from @YeasinSheikh) you need to make sure that these global keys are unique within your application. To do so, you can add a `GlobalKey` to every instance of your `MyHomePage` and use this key combined with the key you use for the `Chip` widgets.

Try this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(key: GlobalKey(), title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // add a required Key param to the constructor and pass it to super
  const MyHomePage({required Key key, required this.title}): super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ScrollController _chipsScrollController = ScrollController();
  String _currentChip = 'Chip 1';
  static const _chips = [
    'Chip 1',
    'Chip 2',
    'Chip 3',
    'Chip 4',
    'Chip 5',
    'Chip 6',
    'Chip 7',
    'Chip 8',
    'Chip 9',
    'Chip 10',
    'Chip 11',
    'Chip 12',
    'Chip 13',
    'Chip 14',
    'Chip 15',
    'Chip 16',
    'Chip 18',
    'Chip 19',
    'Chip 20',
    'Chip 21',
    'Chip 22',
    'Chip 23',
    'Chip 24',     
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 70,
          child: ListView.separated(
            controller: _chipsScrollController,
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 12, 16, 12),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: _chips.length,
            itemBuilder: (final BuildContext context, final int index) {
              return ChoiceChip(
                  // key now will be globally unique 
                  key: GlobalObjectKey('${widget.key}_${_chips[index]}'),
                  label: Text(_chips[index]),
                  selected: _chips[index] == _currentChip,
                  onSelected: (final bool value) {
                    _currentChip = _chips[index];
                    Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                      GlobalObjectKey('${widget.key}_${_chips[index]}').currentContext!,
                      alignment: 0.5,
                    );
                  });
            },
            separatorBuilder: (final BuildContext context, final int index) =>
                const SizedBox(width: 12),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => MyHomePage(key: GlobalKey(),
              title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```